# TStringGrid blanks last column. Why? How to debug?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I've got a `TStringGrid` that is being updated properly and `DrawCell` is drawing properly.  Then on the next update, the cells are being updated properly but the last column is blank. To help debug, I've put one common routine for setting values

```cpp
void __fastcall TF3Frame::SetCell(String s, int Col, int Row)
{
  static int Blank = 0;
  if (s == L"") 
    s = Blank++;
  CResults->Cells[ColIndex[Col]][Row] = s;
}
```

Which will replace any blank values with an incrementing number.

It works as expected with no blank cells, then I do my update and the last column is blank again.

To be clear, when I update it (every time) , there is data in the cell. But when it gets to the `DrawCell` the cell is blank after the 2nd update.

I tried setting a data breakpoint, but Delphi VCL is optimized and variables cannot be seen.

I've even tried subclassing `TStringGrid`, to limit access to the last column, but the VCL design class didn't like that.

I've run out of things to try.  Is there a way to add a callback when a cell is modified? Any other ideas?
I'll try to give psudo code of what's happening.

```
Page load
    does a lookup
    fills in values into CResults(all good)

TComboBox  onChange event, 
   does a lookup
   fills in values into CResults (all good)

TStringGrid DrawCell
   displays the results
   if from page load, CResults->Cells[*][4] has proper values
   if from TComboBox, CResults->Cells[*][4] is NULL

The only difference that I can see, is the event that initially fills in the values.
```

Comment: What kind of "update" are you referring to exactly? What does it look like? What does your drawing code look like? Please provide a [mcve]. Also, what is `ColIndex[]` and why is it being used instead of `Col` as-is?

Comment: ColIndex is an index to the columns as the columns can move in other situations. I shouldn't have had it in this example, as it's not changing. (I used copy paste). The code is massive, but I can tell you the drawing code uses CResult as read only, to get values. I don't know how I would get a minimal reproducible example.  Hoping for some callback or flag or subclassing code to see when it's being set.

Comment: Well, since we can't see how you are doing the lookup, filling in the values, or drawing them, we can't really help you. If the code is too much to post, make a [mcve] as a new project that reproduces the same issue with as little code as possible.

Comment: Yeah, not asking how to fix the code so much as how to go about debugging it. TStringGrid stores the values, but it's all optimized so it's hard to track an individual cell. Something is changing the value, but there seems to be no callback system in place to know when values are being changed.

Comment: "*there seems to be no callback system in place to know when values are being changed*" - you could derive a new class from `TStringGrid` and override the virtual `Update()` method (or at least put a breakpoint in `Update()`), which is called by the `Cells` and `Objects` property setters.

Comment: I tried that, but the Designer seemed to have problems with TMyStringGrid.  I also tried allowing the mismatched type between designer and code, but none of the events seemed to be linked up. Is there a "correct" way to do this?

Comment: I just found it. A menu onClick was being manually called deep down in the code which did the clear. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want designer support for a new class, you have to put it in a Package and install it in the IDE. Otherwise, you can just create an object of the the class in code at runtime, but you won't have designer support for it. Delphi has a concept of Interposer classes so you don't need to install a Package, but that doesn't work in C++, AFAIK.

Comment: That explains it. I thought I had done that with Delphi.